Class multiplication coefficients of symmetric groups
My question is that I was working with some counting problems, and finally the answer should be
$$
\nu_{\mu_1,\mu_2,\mu_3}=\#\{(\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3): \sigma_1\sigma_2\sigma_3=1, \sigma_1\in C_{\mu_1},\sigma_2\in C_{\mu_2},\sigma_3\in C_{\mu_3}\}.
$$
$C_{\mu_i}$ are conjugacy classes in $S_n$. $\sigma_i \in S_n$ are the permutations. With little work we can show
$$
\nu_{\mu_1,\mu_2,\mu_3}=\frac{(n!)^2}{c(\mu_1)c(\mu_2)c(\mu_3)}\cdot \sum_{\chi\in \mathrm{Irr}(S_n)} \frac{\chi(\mu_1)\chi(\mu_2)\chi(\mu_3)}{\chi(1)}.
$$
It's called class multiplication coefficients. Are there any results on these numbers?

There are many results, so what do you need?

Essentially a repeat of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/62088.

I don't know if there are some estimates or specific properties on these numbers just combinatorically. Or it is just too difficult to calculate directly?

There are a vast number of papers on special cases, one example being Goupil's paper at https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X9090054L. I wouldn't be surprised if the general problem is #P-complete. Maybe this is already known. See also https://inria.hal.science/inria-00098749/document.
